# How do i import the contents of a folder, and call individual scripts by name?

Tags: python, python-import, python-class

I want to be able to import the contents of a folder and be able to call functions in classes inside them by name, like say i have example.py i would want to be able to type 'example' with python input commands and be able to run a function inside it

To achieve this I was thinking of maybe using objects such as this but i have really no idea where to start or what best practice would be.

```
class File():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def run()
        dostuff()
```

i was also thinking maybe something like this would work for calling it:

```
files = []
for i in files:
    if i.name == name:
       i.run()
```

I have no idea how I would import the entire file and be able to extract it to a list. All I want to do is just be able to import all files into a folder and be able to run them by name.

I searched on the internet for a while attempting to find an answer to this but couldn't find much that was helpful so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a way you can import python scripts using a function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module . If you then have a standardised name for your function, you can just call m.run() if m is the return value of importlib.import_module(module_name) and run is the name of your function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but here are 2 questions and solutions that might assist

1. How to import other python files from script? [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) & [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)
2. Given a string `"example"` how can I execute the code `import example`? [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: I looked into that, that was very helpful thank you. But what i was asking was if there was a good way i could dynamically call functions inside those imported files, such as if i know there is a run function in the script but i don't know the name of the file. again thank you

Comment: @Turb000 you need to import all python files of a specific directory?